# Template parameter pack peel args in pairs

Tags: c++, c++11, arduino, variadic-templates, microcontroller

I want to create a function for an ESP2866 microcontroller that saves an arbitrary number of configurations to a config file on the filesystem. I found a way to do it and I was wondering if it could be any better.

```
// Saves the configuration values to the file system
template <typename... Args>
void SaveConfig(const char *name, String &value, Args &...args)
{
    Serial.println("Saving config...");
    StaticJsonDocument<JSON_OBJECT_SIZE(2) + 200> doc;
    SetData(doc, name, value, args...);

    File configFile = SPIFFS.open("/config.json", "w");
    if (!configFile)
        Serial.println("Failed to open config file for writing!");

    serializeJson(doc, configFile);
    serializeJson(doc, Serial);
    configFile.close();
}
```

All i would need to do is:

```
doc[name] = value;
```

for each pair of arguments in the parameter pack. My solution was that i created a new function SetData() that calls itself with the parameter pack arguments, peeling off two parameters each iteration:

```
template <typename... Args>
static void SetData(JsonDocument &doc, const char *name, String &value, Args &...args)
{
    doc[name] = value;
    SetData(doc, args...);
}
```

But this creates another problem. When the parameter pack "runs out" it wants to call SetData() with no parameters. So now I have to create an overload of this function with no parameters (except doc).

So is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Do you insist on a template? I would use a `std::vector` (or possibly `std::initializer_list`) of structs (or of `std::pair`s),

Comment: std is not really availabe on microcontrollers. I mean it sort of works but std::vector allocates memory on the heap.

Comment: `std::initializer_list` doesn't. I also would be concerned about templates (especially recursive ones like yours) bloating the binary.

Comment: @FlucTuAte. STL not being available on MCU is not correct either. It is available and can be used, it is no problem to reserve parts of the memory for the heap. True, though, is that it has to be used really carefully. Small heap size and frequent allocations can easily lead to memory getting fragmented that much that further allocations get impossible.

Comment: If you're constrained to C++11, I'm pretty sure the solution you have is as clean as it'll get. With C++17, you might be able to improve it with fold-expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to use templates instead of containers, you can try the following:

```
template<typename ...Args, std::size_t ...I>
void SetDataImpl(JsonDocument& doc, std::tuple<Args...> tup, std::index_sequence<I...>) {
  int dummy[] = {
    (doc[std::get<2*I>(tup)] = std::get<2*I+1>(tup), 0)...
  };
}

template<typename ...Args>
void SetData(JsonDocument& doc, Args &...args) {
  static_assert(sizeof...(args) % 2 == 0, "");
  SetDataImpl(doc, std::forward_as_tuple(args...), std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(args) / 2>{});
}
```

But as @HolyBlackCat mentioned, this way would be better.

```
void SetData(JsonDocument& doc, std::initializer_list<std::pair<const char*, String>> il = {}) {
  for(const auto& elem : il) { // Just auto& maybe. Depends on json library implementation
    doc[elem.first] = elem.second;
  }
}
```